# How to list blogs by anonymous in blog module

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I am able to list blogs by a specific user, e.g. /blog/123 - where 123 is the uid, but when I use /blog/0 I get access denied.

Can someone advise on a config setting to enable /blog/0 to list blogs by anonymous user (i.e. uid = 0), please?

I could implement a hook or override the View or something, just wanted to check if there isn't a config setting somewhere. I couldn't see one, looking so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog route `blog/%user_uid_optional` route provided by the blog module performs a few checks in [`blog_page_user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.module/function/blog_page_user_access/7.x):

```
  // The visitor must be able to access the site's content.
  // For a blog to 'exist' the user must either be able to
  // create new blog entries, or it must have existing posts.
  return $account->uid && 
         user_access('access content') && 
         (user_access('create blog content', $account) ||      
          _blog_post_exists($account));
```

The `$account->uid` part of the conditional check will preclude access to **blog/0** even if anonymous users can create blogs posts.

A module evoking [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) you can override this route behavior by providing your own access callback that excludes the `$account->uid` check:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['blog/%user_uid_optional'])) {
    $items['blog/%user_uid_optional']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_blog_page_user_access';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_blog_page_user_access($account) {
  return user_access('access content') && (user_access('create blog content', $account) || _blog_post_exists($account));
}
```

Comment: +1 upvote and accepted answer: 1) it explains why the URL is not possible out-of-the-boc 2) provides a solution. Thank you!